# Kernel Quantile regression in python

Tags: python, r, regression, quantile

Is it possible to rewrite the core calculation part, [ipop](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/kernlab/versions/0.9-32/topics/ipop), using Python packages?

Here is the corresponding part of the R code.

```r
# Setup QP problem and call ipop
if(!reduced)
  H = kernelMatrix(kernel,x)
else
  H = csi(x, kernel = kernel, rank = rank)
c = -y
A = rep(1,m)
b = 0
r = 0
l = matrix(C * (tau-1),m,1)
u = matrix(C * tau ,m,1)    
                   
qpsol = ipop(c, H, A, b, l, u, r)
```

While Scipy itself does not have a library for quadratic programming, it seems that this could be achieved with an optimizer. Do you foresee any problems?